# How to import an initial file multiple time but only run the code once

Tags: python

Please excuse my English

I have multiple modules within many classes and I want to create an initial file to contain a few numbers of object created from classes. I did this by importing it in another file to use the object that I created. Is there any way for me to run the code in `initial.py` once but import it multiple times for many files? I don't want to run the `__init__` function inside the classes that I have multiple times. I found out that I can do it in a very simple way with if function like this:

```
import role, strategy

i = 1
if (i == 1):
   player = role.Attacker()
   player_strategy = strategy.Attacker()
   i += 1
```

Is there any smarter way to do it?

Comment: Modules are executed only once anyway. Just remove the `if` and the `i`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment why didn't I realize it sooner :)